# How to configure the st kernel module for LTO-6 tape drives?

Tags: performance, kernel, kernel-modules, tapedrive, lto

I found a hint to configure the `st` module [in a mail from 2004 redhat mailinglist](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2004-December/msg04118.html) about a slow LTO-2 drive.

```
modprobe st buffer_kbs=1024 max_buffers=128 max_sg_segs=128 blocking_open=1
```

Are similar settings required for best performance of LTO-6 drives too?
Where do we know the values from? What are the default settings, if no values are passed?

Comment: What can make a difference is the block-size your software reading/writing the tape is using and the amount of eof-marks you write. Setting kernel parameters isn't required for optimal performance these days.

Answer (score 0):

> Are similar settings required for best performance of LTO-6 drives too?

Do you experience bad performance or is the speed not as expected? If no, just stick to the defaults. Otherwise ask the vendor or give more details about your LTO-6 drive.

> Where do we know the values from?

Well, best would be to ask your hardware vendor or check on the manufacturer site and manual for your drive. Lastly you could just trail-n-error, if you experience bad performance.

> What are the default settings, if no values are passed?

Look through `dmesg` and use `modinfo st` to reveal the possible values and defaults. You also could look at `/sys/module/st/parameters/*` to see the current settings. Might be that this is not available.

Comment: @JonasStein Is the drive used for writing to new tapes? Or is it used for overwriting previously used tapes?

Comment: @kasperd it is used for brand new and used tapes. But how does it make a difference?

Comment: @JonasStein New tapes cause much wear on the heads and can lead to reduced capacity and performance. Here I am speaking from experience with LTO-4 tapes. I don't know if that has changed in later generations.

Comment: @JonasStein do you mean "brakes" as in the drive stops and has to restart (aka "shoeshining"), or "breaks" as in the drive is now broken?

Comment: The reason is indeed that I am debugging, why the tape drive brakes (stops) so often. The provided data rate should be more than fast enough. But there could be a problem with the bus or the kernel (module) settings. I expected that all LTO-6 drives need the same parameters. /sys/module/st/parameters/* is not available here.